# how to remove the color on my console VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, console

I have a problem with my vs code (console) when I type a command on the console it colors me the text, here are the details.
Thanks for your help.
[my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEq8P.jpg) 
[my settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWpR9.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [one of the many](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45693) issues caused by winpty.

That "Powershell" in the upper right of your screenshot means that you're using the the regular powershell terminal in VSCode and probably you have those colors set in your powershell.exe (the one that VSCode is using).

So, until this problem is fixed on the "VSCode side", you could try a few things:

- reset any color theme/scheme that you may have applied to your powershell.exe
- since many issues are related with `PSReadLine` you can configure his colors like in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/676140/how-to-set-colors-in-psreadline-in-powershell)
- you can try using the [Powershell Preview extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell-Preview) which acording to [this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/535) enables `PSReadLine` support and solves your problem.

I would give this extension a try, with due warning that the intended functionality is only in Preview mode.

Tell me if I can help any more.